# Frontend pages giving 404 with symfony and apostrophe

Tags: symfony1, apache2, apostrophe

I thinks this question might be on the edge of having to go on serverfault. However, as I'm not sure about the cause of the problem, I'll ask the question here.

I Have a Symfony installation with 2 apps: `frontend` and `backend`
On the frontend I run apostrophe cms and in the backend I have some modules from the doctrine admin generator.

Everything works fine local. However, on my production server, every frontend page after http://mydomain.com/ gives a 404 error. The weird thing is that http://mydomain.com/backend/ works fine. I'm not sure if its my apache config (seeing as /backend/ does work) but I'll paste it here, just to be sure. This is what I have in sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/mysfproject/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/mysfproject/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

  Alias /sf /mysfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/mysfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And it works fine when you access index.php or dev.php directly?

Comment: Yes, http://foo.com/index.php works fine..

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file? http://trac.apostrophenow.org/browser/sandboxes/asandbox/trunk/web/.htaccess

Comment: Yes, that exact same one.. Btw: the exact error I'm getting is: `Not Found The requested URL /foo was not found on this server.`

Comment: erm.. Do you have a routing.yml set up with the a_page route? http://trac.apostrophenow.org/browser/plugins/apostrophePlugin/trunk/config/routing.yml.sample

..but you say it is working locally? What's in the error log? Is everything being rewritten correctly?

Comment: Yes I do have the routing.yml file set up. Apache error log just says `File does not exist: /srv/mysite/web/foo` so I think it must be in the rewriting, but not sure how to check..

Comment: Turns out mod_rewrite was disabled :s Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go ahead and answer it.  You can select it as the correct answer after 8 hours, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out mod_rewrite was disabled. Fixed it by doing `sudo a2enmod rewrite`